Incomplete filtering process using list of keywords with filter and str_detect functions
This is my df in long format:
Tube_patient      variable   value
1 S_PUC_H_001_(1)_G4 WT_Spike_igg1 1053305
2 S_PUC_H_003_(1)_G4 WT_N_igg1       0
3 S_PUC_H_004_(2)_G4 WT_RBD_igg1       0
4 S_PUC_H_006_(8)_G4 IgG1_WT_Spike       0
5 S_PUC_H_018_(1)_G4 IgG1_WT_N       0
6 S_PUC_H_028_(6)_G4 IgG1_WT_RBD 1961326

Here is an option to reproduce the issue using the first 5 rows and the last 5:
> dput(df.infected.melted[c(1:5, 4635:4640), ])
structure(list(Tube_patient = c("S_PUC_H_001_(1)_G4", "S_PUC_H_003_(1)_G4", 
"S_PUC_H_004_(2)_G4", "S_PUC_H_006_(8)_G4", "S_PUC_H_018_(1)_G4", 
"S_PUC_O_007_(6)_G4", "S_PUC_O_025_(1)_G4", "S_PUC_O_038_(1)_G4", 
"S_PUC_O_057_(12)_G4", "S_PUC_O_106_(7)_G4", "S_PUC_O_107_(3)_G4"
), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 290L, 290L, 290L, 
290L, 290L, 290L), levels = c("WT_Spike_igg1", "WTS1_igg1", "WT_RBD_igg1", 
"WTS2_igg1", "WT_NTD_igg1", "Alpha_Spike_igg1", "Beta_RBD_igg1", 
"Beta_Spike_igg1", "Delta_Spike_igg1", "Gamma_Spike_igg1", "Alpha_RBD_igg1", 
"Gamma_RBD_igg1", "Ebola_igg1", "Delta_RBD_igg1", "WT_N_igg1", 
"WT_Spike_igg2", "WTS1_igg2", "WT_RBD_igg2", "WTS2_igg2", "WT_NTD_igg2", 
"Alpha_Spike_igg2", "Beta_RBD_igg2", "Beta_Spike_igg2", "Delta_Spike_igg2", 
"Gamma_Spike_igg2", "Alpha_RBD_igg2", "Gamma_RBD_igg2", "Ebola_igg2", 
"Delta_RBD_igg2", "WT_N_igg2", "WT_Spike_igg3", "WTS1_igg3", 
"WT_RBD_igg3", "WTS2_igg3", "WT_NTD_igg3", "Alpha_Spike_igg3", 
"Beta_RBD_igg3", "Beta_Spike_igg3", "Delta_Spike_igg3", "Gamma_Spike_igg3", 
"Alpha_RBD_igg3", "Gamma_RBD_igg3", "Ebola_igg3", "Delta_RBD_igg3", 
"WT_N_igg3", "WT_Spike_igg4", "WTS1_igg4", "WT_RBD_igg4", "WTS2_igg4", 
"WT_NTD_igg4", "Alpha_Spike_igg4", "Beta_RBD_igg4", "Beta_Spike_igg4", 
"Delta_Spike_igg4", "Gamma_Spike_igg4", "Alpha_RBD_igg4", "Gamma_RBD_igg4", 
"Ebola_igg4", "Delta_RBD_igg4", "WT_N_igg4", "WT_Spike_iga1", 
"WTS1_iga1", "WT_RBD_iga1", "WTS2_iga1", "WT_NTD_iga1", "Alpha_Spike_iga1", 
"Beta_RBD_iga1", "Beta_Spike_iga1", "Delta_Spike_iga1", "Gamma_Spike_iga1", 
"Alpha_RBD_iga1", "Gamma_RBD_iga1", "Ebola_iga1", "Delta_RBD_iga1", 
"WT_N_iga1", "WT_Spike_igm", "WTS1_igm", "WT_RBD_igm", "WTS2_igm", 
"WT_NTD_igm", "Alpha_Spike_igm", "Beta_RBD_igm", "Beta_Spike_igm", 
"Delta_Spike_igm", "Gamma_Spike_igm", "Alpha_RBD_igm", "Gamma_RBD_igm", 
"Ebola_igm", "Delta_RBD_igm", "WT_N_igm", "WT_Spike_FcgR2A", 
"WTS1_FcgR2A", "WT_RBD_FcgR2A", "WTS2_FcgR2A", "WT_NTD_FcgR2A", 
"Alpha_Spike_FcgR2A", "Beta_RBD_FcgR2A", "Beta_Spike_FcgR2A", 
"Delta_Spike_FcgR2A", "Gamma_Spike_FcgR2A", "Alpha_RBD_FcgR2A", 
"Gamma_RBD_FcgR2A", "Ebola_FcgR2A", "Delta_RBD_FcgR2A", "WT_N_FcgR2A", 
"WT_Spike_FcgR2B", "WTS1_FcgR2B", "WT_RBD_FcgR2B", "WTS2_FcgR2B", 
"WT_NTD_FcgR2B", "Alpha_Spike_FcgR2B", "Beta_RBD_FcgR2B", "Beta_Spike_FcgR2B", 
"Delta_Spike_FcgR2B", "Gamma_Spike_FcgR2B", "Alpha_RBD_FcgR2B", 
"Gamma_RBD_FcgR2B", "Ebola_FcgR2B", "Delta_RBD_FcgR2B", "WT_N_FcgR2B", 
"WT_Spike_FcgR3A", "WTS1_FcgR3A", "WT_RBD_FcgR3A", "WTS2_FcgR3A", 
"WT_NTD_FcgR3A", "Alpha_Spike_FcgR3A", "Beta_RBD_FcgR3A", "Beta_Spike_FcgR3A", 
"Delta_Spike_FcgR3A", "Gamma_Spike_FcgR3A", "Alpha_RBD_FcgR3A", 
"Gamma_RBD_FcgR3A", "Ebola_FcgR3A", "Delta_RBD_FcgR3A", "WT_N_FcgR3A", 
"WT_Spike_FcgR3B", "WTS1_FcgR3B", "WT_RBD_FcgR3B", "WTS2_FcgR3B", 
"WT_NTD_FcgR3B", "Alpha_Spike_FcgR3B", "Beta_RBD_FcgR3B", "Beta_Spike_FcgR3B", 
"Delta_Spike_FcgR3B", "Gamma_Spike_FcgR3B", "Alpha_RBD_FcgR3B", 
"Gamma_RBD_FcgR3B", "Ebola_FcgR3B", "Delta_RBD_FcgR3B", "WT_N_FcgR3B", 
"IgG1_WT_RBD", "IgG1_WT_Spike", "IgG1_S1", "IgG1_S2", "IgG1_NTD", 
"IgG1_N", "IgG1_Alpha_RBD", "IgG1_Alpha_Spike", "IgG1_Beta_RBD", 
"IgG1_Beta_Spike", "IgG1_Gamma_RBD", "IgG1_Gamma_Spike", "IgG1_Delta_RBD", 
"IgG1_Delta_Spike", "IgG2_WT_RBD", "IgG2_WT_Spike", "IgG2_S1", 
"IgG2_S2", "IgG2_NTD", "IgG2_N", "IgG2_Alpha_RBD", "IgG2_Alpha_Spike", 
"IgG2_Beta_RBD", "IgG2_Beta_Spike", "IgG2_Gamma_RBD", "IgG2_Gamma_Spike", 
"IgG2_Delta_RBD", "IgG2_Delta_Spike", "IgG3_WT_RBD", "IgG3_WT_Spike", 
"IgG3_S1", "IgG3_S2", "IgG3_NTD", "IgG3_N", "IgG3_Alpha_RBD", 
"IgG3_Alpha_Spike", "IgG3_Beta_RBD", "IgG3_Beta_Spike", "IgG3_Gamma_RBD", 
"IgG3_Gamma_Spike", "IgG3_Delta_RBD", "IgG3_Delta_Spike", "IgG4_WT_RBD", 
"IgG4_WT_Spike", "IgG4_S1", "IgG4_S2", "IgG4_NTD", "IgG4_N", 
"IgG4_Alpha_RBD", "IgG4_Alpha_Spike", "IgG4_Beta_RBD", "IgG4_Beta_Spike", 
"IgG4_Gamma_RBD", "IgG4_Gamma_Spike", "IgG4_Delta_RBD", "IgG4_Delta_Spike", 
"IgA_WT_RBD", "IgA_WT_Spike", "IgA_S1", "IgA_S2", "IgA_NTD", 
"IgA_N", "IgA_Alpha_RBD", "IgA_Alpha_Spike", "IgA_Beta_RBD", 
"IgA_Beta_Spike", "IgA_Gamma_RBD", "IgA_Gamma_Spike", "IgA_Delta_RBD", 
"IgA_Delta_Spike", "IgM_WT_RBD", "IgM_WT_Spike", "IgM_S1", "IgM_S2", 
"IgM_NTD", "IgM_N", "IgM_Alpha_RBD", "IgM_Alpha_Spike", "IgM_Beta_RBD", 
"IgM_Beta_Spike", "IgM_Gamma_RBD", "IgM_Gamma_Spike", "IgM_Delta_RBD", 
"IgM_Delta_Spike", "FcgR2A_WT_RBD", "FcgR2A_WT_Spike", "FcgR2A_S1", 
"FcgR2A_S2", "FcgR2A_NTD", "FcgR2A_N", "FcgR2A_Alpha_RBD", "FcgR2A_Alpha_Spike", 
"FcgR2A_Beta_RBD", "FcgR2A_Beta_Spike", "FcgR2A_Gamma_RBD", "FcgR2A_Gamma_Spike", 
"FcgR2A_Delta_RBD", "FcgR2A_Delta_Spike", "FcgR2B_WT_RBD", "FcgR2B_WT_Spike", 
"FcgR2B_S1", "FcgR2B_S2", "FcgR2B_NTD", "FcgR2B_N", "FcgR2B_Alpha_RBD", 
"FcgR2B_Alpha_Spike", "FcgR2B_Beta_RBD", "FcgR2B_Beta_Spike", 
"FcgR2B_Gamma_RBD", "FcgR2B_Gamma_Spike", "FcgR2B_Delta_RBD", 
"FcgR2B_Delta_Spike", "FcgR3A_WT_RBD", "FcgR3A_WT_Spike", "FcgR3A_S1", 
"FcgR3A_S2", "FcgR3A_NTD", "FcgR3A_N", "FcgR3A_Alpha_RBD", "FcgR3A_Alpha_Spike", 
"FcgR3A_Beta_RBD", "FcgR3A_Beta_Spike", "FcgR3A_Gamma_RBD", "FcgR3A_Gamma_Spike", 
"FcgR3A_Delta_RBD", "FcgR3A_Delta_Spike", "FcgR3B_WT_RBD", "FcgR3B_WT_Spike", 
"FcgR3B_S1", "FcgR3B_S2", "FcgR3B_NTD", "FcgR3B_N", "FcgR3B_Alpha_RBD", 
"FcgR3B_Alpha_Spike", "FcgR3B_Beta_RBD", "FcgR3B_Beta_Spike", 
"FcgR3B_Gamma_RBD", "FcgR3B_Gamma_Spike", "FcgR3B_Delta_RBD", 
"FcgR3B_Delta_Spike"), class = "factor"), value = c(1053304.5625, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 254.552083333333, 121296.802083333, 95.5520833333335, 
174257.552083333, 248007, 75025.5), new_old = c("old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4635L, 4636L, 4637L, 4638L, 
4639L, 4640L), class = "data.frame")

Here I'm trying to perform a filtering process to separate this long df into small ones, that contain only keywords in the variable column, using this code:
# PERFORM THE FILTERING PROCESS
# Define a list of each analyte
keywords_boxplot <- c('Spike', 'WTS1', 'WTS2', 'RBD', 'N', 'NTD')
# Filter the df by string present in the previous list
filtered_dfs <- lapply(keywords_boxplot, function(keyword) {
  pattern <- paste0(keyword, "_")
  df.infected.melted %>% filter(str_detect(variable, pattern))
})
# For each string filtered, you can create a new df
names(filtered_dfs) <- paste0("df.", keywords_boxplot)
# Create each df in the global environment
list2env(filtered_dfs, envir = .GlobalEnv)```
The issue here is that in the ```variable``` column I do have not a common pattern in the position of the keywords (Spike, WST1, and so on), for example (I think that this could be a potential explanation of why my code is not working properly):

KEYWORD AT THE BEGINNING OF THE STRING (WST1)
WTS1_igg2
KEYWORD IN THE MIDDLE OF THE STRING (SPIKE)
Alpha_Spike_FcgR3B
KEYWORD AT THE END OF THE STRING (RBD)
FcgR2B_Gamma_RBD
So the idea is to use the presence of the keyword in the list to filter the ```variable column```: 

keywords_boxplot <- c('Spike', 'WTS1', 'WTS2', 'RBD', 'N', 'NTD')
What can I do to be less strict in the code and detect the keywords of interest? 
At the same time, I need to differentiate between N versus NTD, for example.


For some reason my code is doing the task with the ```Spike``` keyword but not with N or NTD, with WTS1 only recognizing this type of string (this is only with WST1 and WST2, for example): 

KEYWORD AT THE BEGINNING OF THE STRING

Any comment, idea, or correction, is more than welcome!


Hi @Someone_1313, I think your code is incomplete i.e. we don't know what does df.infected contain. If keywords_boxplot contains the pattern you want to detect, you could possibly use str_detect(string, pattern = paste(keywords_boxplot, collapse = "|") where string is the string of text you want to perform detection on. The paste with collapse = "|" basically turns your keywords_boxplot into OR pattern - detect "Spike" OR "WTS1" OR "WTS2".. If you can post your complete data we might be able to help much better

I checked with your option, but I still have the same issue, some strings are recognized correctly and other do not

Please make this reproducible, and more minimal. If you have verified that the melt code works and your long form is correct, then the melt code itself and everything before is irrelevant. Instead of showing where your data came from, please show some sample data in the long format. Include some entries that you are having trouble with, thus demonstrating the problem.

Please share sample data with dput() so it is copy/pasteable. dput(df.infected.melted[1:10, ]) will make copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 10 rows of df.infected.melted - if the first 10 rows have entries that demonstrate the problem, that's great. If not, choose a different subset to share, but you shouldn't need to share more than 10 or 20 rows to demonstrate the problem. 10 or 20 rows, with 2 or 3 patterns, some of which don't work.

Working on it, thank for your comment, I will update the post in brief

I just update the post, please feel free to comment anything to correct and if you understand my issue, thank for the help @GregorThomas

Okay, your code doesn't run. apply gets an error. If I switch it to lapply, then it does run. I get the Spike data frame that matches the pattern "Spike_" with the first 5 rows of your input. It does not match the last 5 rows that have variable equal to "FcgR3B_Delta_Spike" because you put a _ at the end of "Spike_", and as you can see the "Spike" in "FcgR3B_Delta_Spike" is not followed by an underscore. So, if you want to match strings where the pattern occurs at the end, not followed by an underscore, why are you adding the underscore to the end of your pattern?

If you're concerned about partial matches, e.g., "N" matching "NTD" you could prepend your patterns with "(_|^)" which will match an underscore OR the start of the string, and append your patterns with "(_|$)", which will match an undercore OR the end of the string... my guess is that's your issue. Will post as answer.

I see your point, I updated that part of the code in the post (adding apply)
Your idea is to remove "" from the pattern option?
So, as I see I should change "" and add "(_|$)", right?

I applied your idea, for the RBD and Spike keywords, works. However, for N, NTD, WST1 and 2, the filtered df are incomplete
I do not understand why

After running the code in my answer, if you're still having problems, please edit your sample data to include rows that demonstrate the problems.

Thank you for your idea, I'm checking is everything is correct or if I still have issues

Your problem is that your patterns aren't always preceded or followed by an underscore--sometimes they start or end the string. We can use "(_|^)" in regex to match an underscore OR the start of the string, and "(_|$)" to match an underscore OR the end of the string.
As mentioned in comments, I also changed apply to lapply, which seems more appropriate (and doesn't cause an error).
As a final note, I'd strongly encourage you to not use list2env as your last step. Your next steps will be easier if you keep the data in a list.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
keywords_boxplot <- c('Spike', 'WTS1', 'WTS2', 'RBD', 'N', 'NTD')
# Filter the df by string present in the previous list
filtered_dfs <- lapply(keywords_boxplot, function(keyword) {
  pattern <- paste0("(_|^)", keyword, "(_|$)")
  df.infected.melted %>% filter(str_detect(variable, pattern))
})

names(filtered_dfs) <- paste0("df.", keywords_boxplot)
filtered_dfs
# $df.Spike
#           Tube_patient           variable        value new_old
# 1   S_PUC_H_001_(1)_G4      WT_Spike_igg1 1.053305e+06     old
# 2   S_PUC_H_003_(1)_G4      WT_Spike_igg1 0.000000e+00     old
# 3   S_PUC_H_004_(2)_G4      WT_Spike_igg1 0.000000e+00     old
# 4   S_PUC_H_006_(8)_G4      WT_Spike_igg1 0.000000e+00     old
# 5   S_PUC_H_018_(1)_G4      WT_Spike_igg1 0.000000e+00     old
# 6   S_PUC_O_007_(6)_G4 FcgR3B_Delta_Spike 2.545521e+02     new
# 7   S_PUC_O_025_(1)_G4 FcgR3B_Delta_Spike 1.212968e+05     new
# 8   S_PUC_O_038_(1)_G4 FcgR3B_Delta_Spike 9.555208e+01     new
# 9  S_PUC_O_057_(12)_G4 FcgR3B_Delta_Spike 1.742576e+05     new
# 10  S_PUC_O_106_(7)_G4 FcgR3B_Delta_Spike 2.480070e+05     new
# 11  S_PUC_O_107_(3)_G4 FcgR3B_Delta_Spike 7.502550e+04     new
# 
# $df.WTS1
# [1] Tube_patient variable     value        new_old     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $df.WTS2
# [1] Tube_patient variable     value        new_old     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $df.RBD
# [1] Tube_patient variable     value        new_old     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $df.N
# [1] Tube_patient variable     value        new_old     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# $df.NTD
# [1] Tube_patient variable     value        new_old     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

